# What does | tr -d do in bash?

Tags: bash, pipe

#### Can someone walk through what this code is doing?

```
if [ -f "saved.txt" ]; then                // What does -f do?
    rm saved.txt
fi

in=$(echo "{query}" | tr -d "\\")          // How does this work? 
                                           // What does | tr -d "\\" mean?

echo "$in" > saved.txt                     // Is this simply putting the 
                                           // value of $in into saved.txt?
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The initial if statement will test if the file is a regular file. More on [file test operators here](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/fto.html).

This script will echo the characters `{query}` and pipe it to the command `tr`, which with the `-d` will delete characters that are specified. `tr` stands for translate. In this case it takes a SET and per the man page, it will delete backslashes if you use `\\`.

The result is stored in `$in`.

Finally, the result stored in `in` will be outputted to `saved.text`.

> NAME
>          tr - translate or delete characters
>
> SYNOPSIS
>          tr [OPTION]... SET1 [SET2]
>
> DESCRIPTION
>          Translate, squeeze, and/or delete characters from standard input, writing to standard output.
>
> ```
>    -c, -C, --complement
>           first complement SET1
>
>    -d, --delete
>           delete characters in SET1, do not translate
>
>    -s, --squeeze-repeats
>           replace  each  input  sequence  of  a repeated character that is listed in SET1 with a single occurrence of that
>           character
>
>    -t, --truncate-set1
>           first truncate SET1 to length of SET2
>
>    --help display this help and exit
>
>    --version
>           output version information and exit
>
>    SETs are specified as strings of characters.  Most represent themselves.  Interpreted sequences are:
>
>    \NNN   character with octal value NNN (1 to 3 octal digits)
>
>    \\     backslash
> ```

Answer (score 0):

The first part tests if `saved.txt` exists before trying to remove it.

The second part copies the contents of `query` (I'm assuming a typo and that should be `${query}`, not `{query}`) into `in`, minus any backslashes.

The third part, you are correct; it writes the value of `in` to the file `saved.txt`.